# What elements/compounds would be in the body of an alien living in this specific set of environmental conditions?

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology

**What elements could be in the body of an alien that lives under these conditions?**

- 5/16 of the atmosphere contains sulfur (1/16 hydrogen sulfide and 1/4 sulfur dioxide)
- High quantities of sulfuric acid, such that these aliens have evolutionarily adapted to surviving it
- 12 atm pressure at sea level
- Average temperature of 55°C

Comment: Your temperature is totally incompatible with an atmosphere containing sulfur vapour please reword your question to make your intent clear.

Comment: The atmosphere has sulfur dioxide and hydrogen sulfide, not sulfur vapour and hydrogen sulfide and sulfur dioxide are both very much gasses at 55°c

Comment: Your original atmosphere "contains 5/16 sulfur", sulfur isn't a vapour below ~440°C. 5/16ths *sulfur compounds* is a whole different game, that's far less free sulfur for a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There will be sulfur and oxygen and hydrogen.**

Those things are in your atmosphere and there is useful chemistry to be done.  The various sulfur oxides (SO2, SO3) will be present.  Hydrogen comes with H2S and with H2SO4.

**There will be carbon.**

On a recent idea here I proposed micelles made of [organosulfates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organosulfate) - nonpolar carbon chains with a polar sulfate tail.

**There will be metals.**

Chiefly **iron**, because iron is the most common metal and iron is uncommonly fond of sulfur.  Iron will definitely crash the sulfur party.  Other metals are also fond of sulfur and might be there; **copper**, **lead**, **mercury**.  **Vanadium**?

Alkali metals.  **Sodium** and **potassium** are helpful with sulfur chemistry and are common in the universe.  Your creatures will have some of them.

**Phosphorus**.  Phosphorus is to life sort as administration is to a business - not sexy and never in the limelight but absolutely indispensable.  Phosphate buffers would be super helpful to creatures that wanted to moderate the acidity of the ambient H2SO4 to allow certain chemical reactions.

**Boron.**  OK not really.  The others felt sorry for boron and invited him but he stayed home.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a rough percentage of how much of these elements would be in them?

Comment: @Hwuonian - I think it will depend on how big the alien is.  For an interesting comparison look at elemental breakdown of a human vs e.coli.  The E.Coli has relatively more carbon than we do.  We have more water.  We also have a ton more calcium because of the skeleton.   Since we are making this up, take the one that is the closest to your alien (bacterium or human) and substitute half of the carbon for sulfur.